# SQL statement with two tables join and another table

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

Ok, here is the info following your guide. This is the table script + some tables.

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [cn] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [member] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
       [IsArchived] [bit] null
)

GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2](
    [cn] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [member] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
       [IsArchived] [bit] null
)

GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table4](
    [cn] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [member] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
       [IsArchived] [bit] null
)

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table3](
    [ID] [int] not NULL,
    [ProductID] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [ProductOmschrijving] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
    [ProductPrijs] [money] NULL,
)

GO

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('grp-sec-spla-office','john; chris; jack; marc;','112-112','', '');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('grp-sec-spla-office-prof','jack; marc;','114-114','', '');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('grp-sec-spla-office','cees; klaas','112-112','', '');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('grp-sec-spla-office-prof','jan; piet','114-114','', '');
INSERT INTO table4 VALUES ('grp-sec-spla-office-prof','jack; marc;','114-114','', '');
INSERT INTO table4 VALUES ('grp-sec-spla-office','piet; ellen','112-112','', '');
INSERT INTO table4 VALUES ('grp-sec-spla-visio','henk; alwin','112-116','', '');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (1,'112-112','grp-sec-spla-office-eng','10.12');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (2,'114-114','grp-sec-spla-office-prof-2016','5.45');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (3,'112-116','grp-sec-spla-visio-blabla','7.12');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (4,'112-118','grp-sec-ac-office-sta-eng','2.45');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (5,'112-120','grp-sec-ac-office-pro-eng','2,50');
GO
```

My result with the query is:

```
+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------+
| description |      ProductOmschrijving      | ProductPrijs | Total |
+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------+
| 112-112     | grp-sec-spla-office-eng       | 10.12        |     9 |
| 114-114     | grp-sec-spla-office-prof-2016 | 5.45         |     8 |
+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------+
```

But i need to get:

```
+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------+
| description |      ProductOmschrijving      | ProductPrijs | Total |
+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------+
| 112-112     | grp-sec-spla-office-eng       | 10.12        |     9 |
| 114-114     | grp-sec-spla-office-prof-2016 | 5.45         |     8 |
| 112-116     | grp-sec-spla-visio-blabla     | 7.12         |     2 |
| 112-118     | grp-sec-ac-office-sta-eng     | 2.45         |     0 |
| 112-120     | grp-sec-ac-office-pro-eng     | 250.00       |     0 |
+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------+
```

This is the query i use right now:

```
 SELECT
    table1.description,
    table3.ProductOmschrijving,
    table3.ProductPrijs,
    sum((isnull(LEN(table1.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table1.member, ';', '')),-1) + 1) + 
       isnull(LEN(table2.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table2.member, ';', '')),-1) + 1 + 
       isnull(LEN(table4.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table4.member, ';', '')),-1) + 1) AS Total
FROM table1
inner join table3 ON table1.description = table3.ProductID
left outer join table2 ON table1.description = table2.description
AND table2.IsArchived = 0
left outer join table4 on table1.description = table4.description
and table4.IsArchived = 0
where table1.IsArchived = 0
GROUP BY table1.description
    , ProductOmschrijving
    , ProductPrijs
```

The table1, table2, table4 can change (especially the member field). When I add later on (in the future) a new table5 to the query, i need the result to be the same but only the member need to be added to the result. Even if there are no members in the new table5.

Is this more clear? thank you for your time and help.

---

Ahhghh when i was making the whole post i realized that the table3 (the product table) must of course be the leading table. So i edited the query to go from table3 instead of table1. No it's working perfect!!!

```
 SELECT
    table3.ProductID,
    table3.ProductOmschrijving,
    table3.ProductPrijs,
    sum((isnull(LEN(table1.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table1.member, ';', '')),-1) + 1) + 
       isnull(LEN(table2.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table2.member, ';', '')),-1) + 1 + 
       isnull(LEN(table4.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table4.member, ';', '')),-1) + 1) 
       AS Total
FROM table3
left join table1 ON table3.productid = table1.description
and table1.IsArchived = 0
left join table2 ON table3.productid = table2.description
AND table2.IsArchived = 0
left join table4 on table3.productid = table4.description
and table4.IsArchived = 0
GROUP BY table3.productid
    , ProductOmschrijving
    , ProductPrijs
```

and the result:

```
+-----------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------+
| ProductID |      ProductOmschrijving      | ProductPrijs | Total |
+-----------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------+
| 112-112   | grp-sec-spla-office-eng       | 10.12        |     9 |
| 112-116   | grp-sec-spla-visio-blabla     | 7.12         |     2 |
| 112-118   | grp-sec-ac-office-sta-eng     | 2.45         |     0 |
| 112-120   | grp-sec-ac-office-pro-eng     | 250.00       |     0 |
| 114-114   | grp-sec-spla-office-prof-2016 | 5.45         |     8 |
+-----------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: The missing columns are NOT in your query. They are in the subquery but missing from the main query.

Comment: Hi Sean, i know. But when i add them i get an error. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "Product.ProductOmschrijving" could not be bound.

Comment: Just saying you get an error is not very helpful. Stating what the error is would be helpful. In this case I suspect it is because you didn't also add them to the group by.

Comment: Thanks!!! Adding it to the group by was the solution :-) NICE!!!

Comment: Your last two questions are pretty ambiguous. Can you try to explain them in more detail?

Comment: sorry, i try again, first question: I have in both table1 and table2 more records so i added a column called IsArchived (bit, true or false). The only records I want to show in my result are the one that are false (IsAchived). This means for both tables (both can have false records). And the second question: If i have in table1 a member, but in table2 none then my result is none. Can i still show 1 in the result?

Comment: Yes you can do this. Add a where clause "Where table1.IsArchived = 0". Then you want to add a similar predicate to your join to table2 "AND table2.IsArchived = 0"

Comment: And what about question 2? What if one table has a member and the other not? Can is still show the results from the table that has the member?

Comment: Yes. You already have a left join. That is why I said move the predicate to the join. If you put that one in the where clause it would make it an inner join.

Comment: do you have an example of the query? #sorry #and thanks already

Comment: Short of writing the entire thing for you I provided an example above.

Comment: i only mean where do i have to put the 'where's' and what do you mean by 'it would make it an inner join'? i'm just a basic query user. sorry.

Comment: Well if you used the second query I posted in my answer there is only 1 select statement so the where clause goes right before the group by. And the additional join predicate would go at the end of the join to table2.

Comment: SELECT
    table1.description,
    table3.ProductOmschrijving,
    table3.ProductPrijs,
    sum(LEN(table1.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table1.member, ';', '')) + 1 + LEN(table2.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table2.member, ';', '')) + 1) AS Total
FROM table1
INNER JOIN product ON table1.description = table3.ProductID
left outer join  table2 ON table1.description = table2.description
AND table2.IsArchived is null
where table1.IsArchived is null
GROUP BY table1.description
    , ProductOmschrijving
    , ProductPrijs

Comment: I'm almost there I quess. The only problem now is that I have a member in table1, but I don't have a member in table2 (for a particular description). Then my result is Null, but I need that to be 1. Is that possible? Is it also possible to add more tables in the future?

Comment: I nevermind. That was simply add an (isnull) clause. thx.

Comment: Ok, just one little thing. When I have a 4'th table exact the same as table1 and table2 but with more descriptions in it. It only shows the records from table1. On forehand I do not know in which tables there are more descriptions is it possible to still select all from all tables?

Comment: Everything here is so incredibly vague that I would say to say "probably". You have to remember that I can't see your screen and I have absolutely no idea of what you are working on or what you are trying to do. You might want to take a look at this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

To add those to your existing query you need to include them in the list of columns AND the group by.

```
SELECT SUM(table1_total + table2_total) AS Total,
       description
       , ProductOmschrijving
       , ProductPrijs
FROM (
    SELECT
        table1.description,
        table3.ProductOmschrijving,
        table3.ProductPrijs,
        table1.IsArchived,
        LEN(table1.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table1.member, ';', '')) + 1 AS table1_total,
        LEN(table2.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table2.member, ';', '')) + 1 AS table2_total
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.description = table3.ProductID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.description = table2.description
) a
GROUP BY description
    , ProductOmschrijving
    , ProductPrijs
```

OR you could greatly simplify this query like this.

```
SELECT
    table1.description,
    table3.ProductOmschrijving,
    table3.ProductPrijs,
    --table1.IsArchived, --don't think this is required???
    sum(LEN(table1.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table1.member, ';', '')) + 1 + LEN(table2.member) - LEN(REPLACE(table2.member, ';', '')) + 1) AS Total
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.description = table3.ProductID
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.description = table2.description
GROUP BY description
    , ProductOmschrijving
    , ProductPrijs
```